# create html table from sqlite table

Tags: python, html, sqlite, python-2.7

I have a database named "seinfeldFood.sqlite" and it has 4 tables: "episodes", "foods", "foods_episodes", and "food_types". I want to write a program so that users can choose one of the tables from "seinfeldFood.sqlite" and the contents of the table are presented in a HTML file. Besides, the HTML table should 1) have a title the same as the table name and 2) should have a header as the column names for the table.

I write the following code try to add the contents of sqlite table into a HTML file but I got blank html file.

```
import webbrowser
import os
import sqlite3 as sqlite

def getTable(cursor):
    cursor.execute("""SELECT tbl_name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'""")
    tables = [t[0] for t in cursor.fetchall()]
    print tables
    prompt = "Select table name from: %s\n"%" ".join(tables)
    while True:
        table = raw_input(prompt)
        if table in tables:
            return table

def createTable(cursor,tableName):
    category = []
    results = cursor.execute(("""SELECT * FROM %s""")%(tableName))
    for r in results:
        category.append(r[1])
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Category (name)")
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Category (name) VALUES (?)""",("Category",))
    for c in category:
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Category (name) VALUES (?)""", (c,))
    #conn.commit()
    #result_new = cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM Category""")
    #for t in result_new:
        #return t

def getHTML(cursor,tableName):
    html = \
        """<html>
        <head>
        <title>%s</title>
        <script>
        function createTable(%s,%s)
        {
        }
        </script>
        </head>
        </html>
        """%(tableName,cursor,tableName)
    return html    

def viewDatabase(dbname):
    fo = open(os.path.join(dataDir,"tableView.html"),"w")
    fo.write( getHTML(cursor,tablename,))
    fo.close()
    webbrowser.open_new(dbname)
```

test my function (it gives me blank HTML file):

```
connFood = sqlite.connect(os.path.join(dataDir,"seinfeldFood.sqlite"))
cursor = connFood.cursor()

tablename = getTable(cursor)
createTable(cursor,tablename)
getHTML(cursor, tablename,)
viewDatabase("Category")
```

Here is an image of the table:

[image]

Comment: Why are you expecting anything other than a blank HTML file? You don't ever put any actual content in that file, just an empty JS function.

Comment: how to revise it?thanks

Comment: @neymar you revise it by putting an actual table in it (probably instead of an empty `createTable` JS function). Is your actual question "How do I create an HTML table with Python?"

Comment: I just do not know how to put an table into HTML. I want to copy the contents of a database table (sqlite) to HTML to be a HTML table

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about a lot of core concepts.
1) If you already have an sqlite table: you don't need the "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"
2) javascript to populate a HTML table?

You table code in pure HTML would contain something like this:

```
html_part='<table>'
for t in result_new:
    html_part=html_part + '<tr><td>' + t + '</td></tr>'
html_part=html_part + '</table>
```

Then Insert the html_part at the correct place in you generated html doc.

You are probably way better off by using a webframework. Try http://web2py.com

Then you could have a editable and searchable TABLE of your DB by using a smartgrid.

Comment: Did you try my code? -> you can paste it in your code where you mention: #result_new